# SAPUi5 Odatamodel V4 setHeaders missing

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am wondering in `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.OdataModel` there is a method provided `setHeaders`, for setting custom HTTP Headers.

In `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel` this method is missing.

How can I set custom headers when using oData v4?

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an api called changeHttpHeaders for updating http headers. Unfortunately it is available only from 1.71.0.

Answer (score 0):

If your UI5 version is less that 1.71.0, you can use the below method to setup your custom headers.

```
        setApplicationIDHeader: function (headerName, headerValue) {
        var o = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
            var res = o.apply(this, arguments);
            //Replace below line and use your own logic to identify your request
            if (arguments[0] === "GET" && arguments[1].indexOf("companyContext") > -1) {
                this.setRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue);
            }
            return res;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Please share more sample code where to add this code snipplet ? As fas as i see you are completely bypassing the OdataModel and doing a usual GET XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: You would usually do it in init (of your controller/component), or anywhere where you have access to the <headerValue>. In the exit method (of controller/component), ensure that you assign the original function back to XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open.